# ViewModel cleared in permission change

Tags: android, android-studio, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel

I'm trying to save some information about the user in an AndroidViewModel but if I'm turning off a permission while the application is in the background the ViewModel is recreated. any reason?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about this, but if you change permissions from your app settings, then your app will do a soft recreation and saved data will be lost. Solution: save data in bundle or internal storage (SharedPreferences etc.)

Comment: Post the code to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @SamuelRobert solved the problem. Apprantley ViewModel won't servive all configuration changes. only a few of them...

Comment: @OfekRegev can you share your solution?

Comment: @ErselanKhan my solution was to save the data in local storage